# Make twig plugins by dynamically horizontal reusing via "use" (not "include")

Tags: plugins, twig, user-defined-functions, dynamic-content, twig-extension

## Need: A dynamic template loaded from a DB

I need to present a JSON object via "template plugins" that will come from a database (defined outside the application itself). The plugin will be applied only if a plugin exists.

For this example, let's assume I have this object of type "Reservation" that contains a sub-object of type "Flight":

```
{
    "id": "ABC-XYZ",
    "reservationDate": "2020-09-23",
    "state": "paid",
    "flight":
    {
        "origin": "BCN",
        "destination": "MAD",
        "airline": "VY"
    }
}
```

## Rules

- The controller will call a page template passing multiple objects.
- The page template will "use" or "include" (see later more info) an `object.html.twig` and will display it.
- The `object.html.twig` will do this:

  - If there's not any known plugin able to handle this type of object, the template will display a `<pre>` with the object converted to YAML. This will be mainly act as a "default" plugin or "fallback" plugin.
  - If there's a known plugin able to handle the object, the object will be sent to the plugin (which is not anything else than another twig template).

    - In this case, the plugin should be able to separate "parts" of "interpretable" results to make them "nice" and leave the rest into an object that will be, in turn, displayed again with the original "default" plugin.
    - If there are parts of the object that are in turn interpretable, they will be in turn passed to other plugins.

## Example "desired" outputs

### Sample 1. No plugin available

[image: No plugin available]

### Sample 2. Plugin 'reservation' available. Interprets the state in green. Also removes the redundant data of the ID

[image: Reservation plugin]

### Sample 3. Same than 2 but also plugin 'flight' available, able to process the flight block. Formats the texts and makes a lookup of the airline full-name

[image: Flight plugin]

### Sample 4. Plugin 'flight' available, able to process the flight, that in turn knows that the origin and the destination are "airports" and passes them into the corresponding nested 'airport' plugin, because they are "reusable" objects not only in the "flight" plugin but also in many other places in the application, so they are defined appart

[image: Airport plugin]

## What I have already explored

I know that doing it via 'include' it could work. But let's take a look at the differences between 'use' and 'include':

The major difference between `include` and `use` in twig is that:

- When you `include` a template, it's direct HTML 'inserted there' where you can use the `{{ }}` operator for printing and `{% %}` for control flow (set variables, ifs, fors, etc.). The renderer will process it straight forward. But defining a new block via `{% block myNiceBlock %}` is forbidden.
- When you 'use' a template, it's pre-loaded, and blocks are permitted. There's no rendering of the included block. Then, from the caller, you use a {{ block( 'whatever' ) }} to tell the renderer to go and render that specific block.

The 'include' is more rudimentary. The `use` allows *horizontal reusing* and allows itself to auto-organize itself with other sub-blocks called by the parent block, all in one single file.

For example, in the airports example, if there are N images, in a `include` you should put the wrapper HTML directly in the file, do a loop and inside the loop write the inner HTML.

Instead in the `use` approach you'd do an `airport` block which in turn loops over the images and just calls the block `airportImage` which is defined in another block in the same file, thus facilitating clean-coding.

## Requirement

1. The application should not be re-deployed when new plugins are created. They must be loaded from a DB or any other dynamic system, as the plugins will be written by "users of the application" as they need it. No deploy allowed.
2. The plugins should be written in terms of a "block-able" twig template, so need to be 'use'-able.

## Question

Discovering "which" plugin to call is not a problem. Assume that whoever (the controller, the twig itself, whoever really) can discover for this example that a "reservation" plugin exists somewhere. How can I `use` it from the page? When the `reservation` is rendering it "asks if a flight plugin" is available. If not, all to the YAML. If it is, how can then dynamically tell the reservation to `use` the flight?

In short: How do I force a template to dynamically `use` (not `include`) templates that, in turn, comes from the database (not from fixed files)?

NOTE: If this info is useful: I'm using Symfony 5 with webpack.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with `The application should not be re-deployed when new plugins are created`? As from your text, a plugin consist of a twig template. How will you not redeploy the application when a new twig template is added or are you trying to store twig template in the database itself?

Comment: Correct (answering in multiple comments): The same way we don't deploy the application any time an agent "creates a new reservation", there's a POST page to create it and a GET page to view it, the whole point of my question is that if they are not happy on how an object is displayed, they can POST a new "twig-syntax text in a textarea in a form" and give it some kind of name and then GET the object to the renderer does a "select" on the data and another "select" on the available plugins.

Comment: The "page" and "main object renderer" are in fact in the application (as they don't change). The question is: If it's about "inlining" content I could just create a TwigExtension and at any given point do something like: `{{ my_plugin_engine( var_with_plugin_name, var_with_plugin_data ) }}` but that would act more like the `include` thing. I'd like to do something more like `{% my_plugin_loader( var_with_plugin_name %}` at some point and then do `{{ block( var_with_block_name_defined_in_plugin ) }}`.

Comment: IDK if that's even possible. I guess yes and it's only I don't know how. Maybe it's not possible at all. I've noted that `use` can't accept a variable when used in a file. It requires it is a hard-coded string. I wonder if there's kind of way to do it dynamically.

Comment: You definitely can load dynamic templates into twig with [template_from_string](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/template_from_string.html) . I do have  several systems in place which load dynamic content, but I predefine the template in my database, (e.g. Product: `id`, `name`, `template`, ...). In my twig template I do something like `{% for product in products %}{{ include [ ('Path/To/Product/'~product.getTemplate()), 'Path/To/Product/default.html', ] }}{% endfor %}`. So if no template is defined (or missing) it falls back to a default view.

Comment: But if you store the full template in the database you could do something like `{% if porudct.getTemplate()|trim %}{{ include(template_from_string(product.getTemplate())) }}{% else %}{% include 'default.html' %}`. Don't know if this helps to give you an idea?

Comment: It's a first stepping stone. But it seems you include "inline" templating. I look for something similar able to "include block definitions from a string" that later on I can re-use by calling `{{ block( 'some_block_name_defined_in_the_dynamically_loaded_part' ) }}`

Comment: Yeah i know, but you can't do `{% use foo %}` in twig, this will throw a `SyntaxError` (*The template references in a "use" statement must be a string.*) So the template u'd want to `use` would need to physically exist, meaning you would need to create/store a template whenever u want to create a new plugin. As you don't want to redeploy that would mean u'd need to store the template from your backend to the filesystem